# How many matchsticks minimum can you move to make this true?

Tags: matches

[image: Puzzle]

Ok here are some rules because it would be too easy/too hard without them

1. Round to nearest 100th
2. The first number cannot be an integer
3. Needs to be an equality
4. No mixed numbers

Hint:

> The equal sigh need not be aligned.

Comment: What matchsticks?

Comment: @f'' They're figurative :P

Comment: Changing the rules 3 times...

Comment: What are "mixed numbers"?

Comment: @Poolsharker This is a lesson for me to always think a problem through.

Comment: @JonathanAllan a whole number and a fraction together.

Comment: @bleh you know that can easily be remedied by writing it in fraction form............................

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer after second puzzle change

Can do it moving $2$ matches (maybe there is a way for $1$?)

> Take $2$ from the top of the right hand side's numerator and move them to its denominator:
>  Left - Roman numerals $\frac{X}{XX}=\frac{10}{20}=0.5$
>  Right - Tally marks $\frac{||}{||||}=\frac24=0.5$

---

Answer post puzzle change (without fourth rule)

Easily done for **equality**, ***moving*** only $1$ match

> [image: 1 move post puzzle change solution]
>  Left - Roman Numerals $I\frac{X}{XX}=1\frac{10}{20}=1.5$
>  Right - Roman Numerals $\frac{III}{II}=\frac32=1.5$

---

Answer pre puzzle change (add matches, not rule 3 or 4)

Easily done for **equality** with $2$ more matches

> [image: 2 match solution]
>  Left - Roman Numerals $\frac{X}{XX}=\frac{10}{20}=0.5$
>  Right - Tally marks $\frac{|}{\frac{||||}{||}}=\frac1{\frac42}=\frac24=0.5$

...or for a **true** statement, we can do it with just $1$ match

> strike the equals to a not equals $\frac{X}{XX}\neq\frac{||||}{||}\rightarrow 0.5\neq2$

Comment: Sorry, changed it. Look at it

Comment: Updated to fit the changed puzzle.

Comment: Agh, your answer is better than my intended answer. I'll accept it, but find the *cleverest* answer if you can.

Comment: I'll keep it at accepted, but I need to change the rules 1 more time :(

Answer (score 4):

Move

> 0

matchsticks to make the equation true:

> The left side is in [Suzhou numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suzhou_numerals), reading 4/44. The right side is $\frac{1\left|1\right|}{11}$: 1 times the absolute value of 1, divided by 11. Both sides equal 1/11.

Answer (score 3):

I'll take a stab, not sure if this is what is being asked...

Answer:

> 1

Reason:

> Move one match stick from the top of the second number to the bottom of the second number, changing the first vertical line into a V, 10/20 = 3/6

Comment: Sorry changed it. Sorry for misconception

Comment: @Bleh No problem, updated my answer.  Take a look and let me know if there is something missing.

Comment: |/ Is not a v. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

This seems a little too simple to be correct, but..

> My guess is 2.

Method:

> Move 2 matchsticks from IIII to the denominator, so it becomes 10/20 = 2/4.

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

> 2

How?

> X    IIII
> ---=-----
> XX   I I

becomes

> XI    III
> ---=-----
> XI    III

by way of:

> Moving one of the cross matches on the second X to the top (and straightening them out), and moving one of the 4 matches to the bottom.

Or, simply put...

> 11/11 = 3/3, or 1=1.

Comment: Did you read the rules?

Comment: Which rule am I breaking?

Comment: Rule 2. 11/11 == integer

Comment: No, 11/11 is a fraction. An integer is a whole number that is not a fraction. Just because 11/11 becomes a whole number does not mean it is an integer.

Comment: No, 11/11 is an integer. What I mean, is that the 1st *number* not set of numerals, is not an onteger

Comment: You and I then have very different views on what an integer is, as does apparently the mathematics world.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42563/discussion-between-bleh-and-josh).